# Why is this for loop using +=?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm having trouble understanding why this for loop is `text += cars[i]...` and not just `text = cars [i]...`

Here is the full script

```js
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var i, len, text;
for (i = 0, len = cars.length, text = ""; i < len; i++) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Try it and find out. If it was `text = ...`, then `text` would only reflect the final iteration.

Comment: not sure which part of `+=` confuses you ... `text += cars` .... is `text = text + cars` ... and `'string1' +  'string2'` results in `string1string2` -

Comment: Do you know what `+=` does?

Comment: @JaromandaX, believe you have best comment. Consider making it an answer so can be accepted?

Comment: @asantaballa - I don't believe in posting answers for what I consider to be `Javascript 101` type questions - a javascript programmer should know what `+=` is within the first hour of their javascript programming journey :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, understand and hope did not offend. Just see many people lose credit when without realizing it when they in fact answered the question. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assignment

`+=` is assignment and addition

---

so if
`text += 'abc'`

and `text` was initially `def`,

the result will be `defabc`

---

in your case, the result would be

`BMW<br/>Volvo</br>Saab<br/>Ford<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

The += operator, such as: x += y, is the same thing as writing x = x + y. In your example, each item in the cars array is being added to a new variable, text, with a 'br' tag inserted between them. It should list all of the cars listed in your array one above the other. If you just used the = operator, the 'text' variable would be overwritten several times until the loop ends, thus you would just see the entry 'Ford' as it's the last in the array.

Answer (score 0):

using += 
the output is 
BMW
Volvo
Saab
Ford

So basically since its a for loop , on each iteration the value of text is built as 
BMW
Volvo
Saab
Ford

If you remove the + from the script
on each iteration the value of text will be replaced by the car[i]
and the end value of the variable text will be Ford